# Ideal of germs of functions vanishing at p

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Let $M^m$ be a smooth manifold, $p \in M$, and the ideal $I_p=\{f \in C^\infty(M) : f(p)=0 \}$ of the algebra of germs $C^\infty(M)$. Show that:

a) $df_p=0, \forall f \in I^2_p$;

b) $I_p/I^2_p$ is a m-dimensional vector space;

c) $T: T_pM \longrightarrow (I_p/I^2_p)^*$ given by $T(v)(f+I^2_p)=df_p(v)$ defines a linear isomorphism, in which $(I_p/I^2_p)^*$ denotes the dual space of $I_p/I^2_p$.

I proved (a) - too easy - but I'm stuck with (b) and (c). Anyway, if (b) is proven and $T$ is shown to be injective, it's done. But I'm stuck with that too.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For b) and injectivity in c), use Taylor development around zero in a local chart centered at $p$.

Comment: This needn't work for functions that are not real analytic. I believe you want to use the expansion $f(x)-f(0) = \sum x_i g_i(x)$, with $g_i(0)=\partial f/\partial x_i (0)$.

Comment: I think that you can just use that (assumign $f(0)=0$) $f$ is congrugent to $\sum_i a_ix_i$ mod $I_0^2$ for some numbers $a_1$, \dots ,$a_n$. This does not use any analyticity assumption, so I don't really see a problem.